# Spring Boot : "Cannot set level: INFO, ERROR for 'org.springframework'" using logback-spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, websphere-8

My application is running in V 1.5.10.RELEASE, to trace my logs in files, i was basically used the **logback-spring.xml**

When the handler catch and throw an exception of type  **"message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"**
the error was badly reassembled :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-11-12T10:59:58.124Z",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "env": "PRD",
  "laas_apcode": "xxxx",
  "laas_type": "service_logs",
  "laas_retention": "quarter",
  "laas_token": "0000000x",
  "organizationalEntity": "xxxx",
  "apName": "xxx-xxxx",
  "apVersion": "0.4.9-1911",
  "nodeName": "xxxx",
  "labels": {
    "userId": "",
    "sourceIp": "",
    "layer": "",
    "rootCorrelationId": "",
    "correlationId": "",
    "parentCorrelationId": ""
  },
  "loggerName": "o.s.b.logging.LoggingApplicationListener",
  "message": "Cannot set level: INFO, ERROR for 'org.springframework'",
  "exception": {
    "stackTrace": ""
  }
}
```

in my application.yml i set this :

```
# Logging Configurations   
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: WARN
    org.springframework: INFO, ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting multiple levels on one package is not allowed

```
# Logging Configurations   
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: WARN
    org.springframework: INFO
```

this will show all message of level `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR` for package `org.springframework`

and all message of level `WARN`, `ERROR` for package `your.package`